# Activity tab is missing from the user profile

Tags: support, profile-page

The activity no longer appears in the tab strip in the middle of the page on my user profile.  Is it gone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some of the tabs have been moved to the top of the page in the user profile:

[image: tabs at top]

Comment: ah.. I missed that

Comment: Again one of those important changes that will in particular puzzle users on the other stackexchange sites. If they don't know the "Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange" page, they have bad luck. I looked around several minutes on my profile page and didn't find my recent activity; thought it had gone due to some temporary bug. Some hours later I went to meta.SO and luckily was informed that my favorite "Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange" had been edited. Now I found it, and the new design is OK, but **some kind of general notification would have been great**.

Comment: Why is there a reputation tab in both sections?