# Two favorite tabs on per site Metas

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, per-site-meta

[image: Why two favourite tabs?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We didn't see this one since moderators view a different set of tabs...but it's fixed in the next build.  The favorites tab should now appear only at the top for any profile.

Answer (score 0):

A [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82395/activity-tab-is-missing-from-the-user-profile/82397#82397) moved the favorites to the top of your profile among other tab changes.  I suggest refreshing the page as I only see the favorites at the top.

Comment: imm, I am still seeing it [two](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61/cbrulak?tab=stats) even on incognito window and also hard refresh with ctrl+F5.

Comment: @S.Mark - On your profile I can see two favorites. One on top and other below. I think it is only if you see other's profiles and not on your own profile when you click on header row and go to your profile.

Comment: @S.Mark, yes, sorry I don't see it for me, but I do see it on your profile.